# Given a number, how to find that many colours that are well-distinguishable?

Tags: color, color-theory, automation

I'm interested in getting an method for obtaining `n` well-distinguishable colours, where `n` is just a given number. The purpose is for it to be implemented in an algorithmic way.

I have read other questions on this topic 
([this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/7960), 
[this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/3682), 
[this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/4623) and
[this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/11361)),
but none of them provides an self-contained way how to generate the colours. (They, in general, say: "Go to this website and put `n` there as input.")

As well, I know that I can equally distribute  the hues of the colours, but then:

1. Good balancing between number of different hues and number of different saturations and lightnesses is necessary (and I don't know how to make it well).
2. The same distance in hue doesn't mean the same distance for a human:

   [image]

   In the example, certainly the left one is less recognizable than the right one, yet the colours are only some RGB permutations.

Comment: 1: find maximum number of unique colors determined by the system you are using to represent them. 2: determine the minimum difference between 2 colors that a "healthy human" can distinguish. 3: divide the maximum number of colors by that distance. << that (lets call this x) is the largest acceptable input from the user. 4: RNG a starting color. 5: divide x by n from user (to get y). 6: add y to start color n times. 7: show resulting colors.

Comment: Once I know how to generate the colours (and you can show me the way with drawings in a colour space or whatever), I shall be able to make it into a real algorithm. The problem lies in making distinguishable colours, not in making a computer program.

Comment: Reopened because of the edit. I cleaned the comments, you are more than welcome to continue the conversation in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/graphic-design-corner).

Comment: There was [an excellent answer to this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/46469) posted on the gamedev.SE site by Sam Hocevar recently.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen That answer (basically, evenly spaced points on a hue wheel) is a good start but if differentiability and large numbers of colours are your main concerns, you'll reach a point where it's better to add a row higher and lower in lightness and/or lower in saturation than adding more spaces on the hue wheel. Lots of good comments too.

Comment: can imagine a good non-code/maths answer like "Here's a quick explanation of HSL, with a 3D diamond diagram. Note how you can use more hue divisions towards the outer centre of the HSL diamond. Here's a quick explanation of relative luminance, and note about colour blindness combinations. So, take X divisions round the 360 degrees of hue, then X-n times round 1 step up and down in saturation and lightness, and repeat Y times - adjusting for relative luminance and to avoid bad contrasts for colour blindness"

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question well, you should definitely take a look at IWantHue at http://tools.medialab.sciences-po.fr/iwanthue/
There you just enter (like you say) a numbner and it autogenerates colors that play well together. But, they also have some theory on the issue. Good luck...

Comment: Hi Lim, welcome to GD. That looks like a great website, thank you for suggesting it!