# Rudimentary explanation — "soft (k-means)" vs. "hard (Force vector)"?

Tags: color, terminology

[I found this website thanks to user Lim](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/16445). But please explain ***like I'm five*** the two options below.

1. What does "soft" vs. "hard" mean?
2. "(k-means)" vs. "hard (Force vector)"?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: I changed some of your titles because, honestly, a 5 year old isn't going to grasp some of them no matter *how* they are explained. `:)` Roll back if you think I was wrong in making any change.

Comment: @Scott no problem. out of curiosity, what age do you think is more fitting? 14?

Comment: For age, I'd think 10+ possibly, once spacial relationships are more understood. But I'll be honest, I'm not overly exposed to any 5 or 10 years olds, so I may not be the absolute best judge here. Other's may be better.. sounds like a good question possibly -- at what age can basic design theories be comprehended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is explained on [this page](https://medialab.github.io/iwanthue/theory/). Basically "hard" pushes the values apart, which causes the points to be as far away as they can be. While "k-means" uses clustering, in other words tries to find the center of a division of space, thus not being as extreme as the latter.

So basically the difference is like asking:

- A group of people, in a room, to be as far away from each other as they can
- and dividing a room into equally big spaces and have them stand in the middle of the space.

Thus in the first case they tend to be near the walls, in the later not so much. But I'm not sure a 5 year old can appreciate the difference.