# Can Adobe Photoshop automatically pick Contrastive or Complementary colors?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

To help me find Contrastive/Complementary colors, I have been relying on websites like https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/3815, https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/5159, https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/8084, https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/16445, https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/17536.

Can Adobe Photoshop  accomplish this offline? I use Adobe Photoshop 23.1.1 on Windows 10.

***By the bye, shouldn't some of these questions be closed as duplicates?***

Comment: @Scott ok. I removed that sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop has an internal links to load an *external* resources... Both Adobe Color Schemes, and Prisma are color palette tools one can load via `Window > Extensions...`

[image]

These essentially load a web site's tools as a panel...

For my use, I always find them horribly slow to load and annoying (Your milage may differ). It's easier for me to simply visit a web site dedicated to color palettes.

---

Even though you can load palette generating panels in Photoshop, it's **not** going to *choose* colors for you.

So "can Adobe Photoshop automatically pick color... " **No**.

It can show you what a palette dictates as complimentary/contrastive, but it won't "choose" any color for you.